# C# SendKeys to foreground window in Windows 7 not working

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to build a global hotkey application with C# in Visual Studio 2012 to run on Windows 7.  I have everything working except the SendKeys are never showing in the application.

Here is the code I am using to send the keystrokes:

**Updated** to debug with `GetFocusedWindow` example.

```
StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder(256);
IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
GetClassName(hWnd, className, className.Capacity);
Debug.WriteLine("Foreground window: {0}={1}", hWnd.ToInt32().ToString("X"), className);
hWnd = GetFocusedWindow();
GetClassName(hWnd, className, className.Capacity);
Debug.WriteLine("Focused window: {0}={1}", hWnd.ToInt32().ToString("X"), className);

SendKeys.Send("Hello World");
```

When I debug the program, focus Notepad, and hit the hotkey I get the following debug message and the keystrokes are never inserted into Notepad:

```
Foreground Window: 4F02B6=Notepad
Focused Window: 1B6026A=WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.bf7d44_r11_ad1
```

How can I send keystrokes to the current foreground window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreground windows doesn't necessary mean *focused* window. A child window of the top-level foreground window may have the focus, while you're sending keys to its parent.

Retrieving the focused child window from another process is a bit tricky. Try the following implementation of `GetFocusedWindow`, use it instead of `GetForegroundWindow` (untested):

```
static IntPtr GetFocusedWindow()
{
    uint currentThread = GetCurrentThreadId();

    IntPtr activeWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
    uint activeProcess;
    uint activeThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(activeWindow, out activeProcess);

    if (currentThread != activeThread)
        AttachThreadInput(currentThread, activeThread, true);
    try
    {
        return GetFocus();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (currentThread != activeThread)
            AttachThreadInput(currentThread, activeThread, false);
    }
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetFocus();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool AttachThreadInput(uint idAttach, uint idAttachTo, bool fAttach);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);
```

**Updated** to address the comment:

> When I use this function it sets the focus to my application window.

It's hard to tell what's wrong on your side, the following works for me when the focus is inside Notepad:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var className = new StringBuilder(200);
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        IntPtr focused = GetFocusedWindow();
        GetClassName(focused, className, className.Capacity);
        var classNameStr = className.ToString();
        this.Text = classNameStr;
        if (classNameStr == "Edit")
            SendKeys.Send("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use this function it sets the focus to my application window.

Comment: Updated question to show debug with GetFocusedWindow.

Comment: @JamesA, I can't repro this. Could you post a small WinForms app source that can help repro'ing?

Comment: It appears to be an issue with a service not being allowed to interact with the desktop.  I have solved it by breaking the app into a service and a client connected via WCF.  Thank you for all of the help.